# How to select label text in GEB?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, spock, geb

I have a select drop down which will display an error if a value is not selected.

```
<div class="field contain" >
<select name="myselect" id="myselect" class="error" >
    <option value="0">--select a value--</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<label for="myselect" generated="true" class="error" style>Please select at least one option</label>
</div>
```

I want to validate if this error label has been displayed using GEB.  Tried to select it with 'error' selector does not work.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Abhijith

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work?

```
assert $("select.error option").text() == "--select a value--"
```

Comment: I want to select text on label(not select).  But your suggestion works if I want to select first option in dropdown.  Thanks.

Comment: I had posted this question on Geb mailing list and got answers there. $(".error", 1).text() and $("label", for: "myselect").text() both works

Comment: Please avoid double posting in short succession. This just creates more work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
assert $("label", for:"myselect").text() == "Please select at least one option"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please provide an explanation along with your code to provide the best possible answer. Kindly read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS selector.

```
$('label[for=myselect]').text()
```

This one selects label tag with value of the "for" attribute = myselect. Then "text()" method returns it's body: "Please select at least one option"